# SQL Server Master-Detail query with forcing a single detail record

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a query where i need to join two table that have no relation and to seek only record where child retails == 1:

```
SELECT dbo.BILL_INFO.BILL_NUMBER,
       dbo.BILL_INFO.BILL_DATE,
       dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.SERVICE_CODE,
       dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.SERVICE_FEE,
       dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.REQUESTED_QUANTITY
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO
    INNER JOIN dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL
        ON dbo.BILL_INFO.BILL_NUMBER = dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.BILL_NUMBER
           AND dbo.BILL_INFO.PAY_MODE_ID = dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.PAY_MODE_ID
           AND dbo.BILL_INFO.CASHIER_ID = dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL.CASHIER_ID
```

So, all records where BILL_INFO_DETAILs = 1

I'll be ultimately using EF so:

```
var test = from billInfo in context.BILL_INFOS
           join billInfoDetail in context.BILL_INFO_DETAILS
               on new {billInfo.BILL_NUMBER, billInfo.PAY_MODE_ID, billInfo.CASHIER_ID}
               equals new
               {
                   billInfoDetail.BILL_NUMBER,
                   billInfoDetail.PAY_MODE_ID,
                   billInfoDetail.CASHIER_ID
               }
           where billInfo.REMARKS.Contains(passNumber.ToString())
           select new
           {
               billInfo.BILL_NUMBER,
               billInfo.BILL_DATE,
               billInfoDetail.SERVICE_CODE,
               billInfoDetail.SERVICE_FEE,
               billInfoDetail.REQUESTED_QUANTITY
           };
```

So, if BILL_INFO and BILL_INFO_DETAIL had a relation, I would have said in the where clause: w.BILL_INFO_DETAILS.Count() == 1 (All bill with only one bill detail)

How do I go about doing this as there is no relation?

[image: DDL]

Comment: How is there no relation, when you're already joining on 3 fields? I have a feeling that `BILL_NUMBER` + `PAY_MODE_ID` + `CASHIER_ID` is already unique for each relation

Comment: This question is not very clear, can you provide DDL, sample data and expected results?

Comment: This table has bad data and won't allow a relation so it is always a manual relationship in reports

Comment: In what way won't it "allow a relation". Do you get an error message? Unexpected data? as is the question makes no sense

Comment: When you say "no relation", do you mean "no foreign key"? That's not the same thing, but I think is what's causing the confusion.

Comment: No relation, ATM, mean cannot create a relation due to many reasons that I'm not supposed to fix because this is a live running financial dump-like DB. I have a read-only access to it. Because there never were any sort of relations in this Oracle 6 DB, there exists a number of detail records that have no parent(s)